# How to send the zip file of type net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile which is password protected in mail?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I was using MimeMessageHelper to attach a file like CSV, TXT and XML and send to mail. It was working perfectly i.e I was getting mail with attached file (.CSV, TXT, XML).

But now client requirement has been changed, now they are expecting a zip file with password protected, that is why I am creating the zip (`net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile`) and adding all those file in zip with password protected.

The problem is I am not able to attach zip file of type `net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile` in `MimeMessageHelper.addAttachment()` method. This is because `addAttachment( String ,java.io.File)` or `addAttachment( String ,org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamSource)` method of class MimeMessageHelper are acceptiong mentioned data type, meanwhile I have zip file of `type net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile`.

Note: I already have created a zip file, just I want to attached zip file in MimeMessageHelper object and send.

Comment: Aside: it seems that your specification process with your client needs to be improved. While it is fine to work in an agile manner, if the client is letting you do development work that is not what they want, you have a communication problem that needs fixing.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Pro-tip: when posting here, please make use of your Shift key, so that the usual case rules of English are observed, to the best of your ability. Questions here are either preserved for future readers or closed, so it makes sense to make them as readable as you can.

Comment: "I am not able to attach zip file of type" - why not? It will help to be more specific than this.

Comment: @halfer

i am not able to attach zip file because addAttachment( String ,java.io.File) or add Attachment( String ,org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamSource)  method of class MimeMessageHelper are acceptiong mention data type , mean while i have zip file of type net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile

That is why i am not able to attach zip file.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this javadoc](http://javadox.com/net.lingala.zip4j/zip4j/1.3.1/net/lingala/zip4j/core/ZipFile.html) which I think is the one of your `ZipFile` class reveals a `getFile()` method which should provide you with a `File` representing the zip archive that you'll be able to attach to your email with the `MimeMessageHelper.addAttachment(String attachmentFilename, File file)` method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Aaron.
it seems i am looking for that only, i also referred the doc what you have shared with me yes getFile() method is returning File Object. 
let me test, will get back to you.